# OpenCV assertion failure

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, path, jupyter

I am trying to try to collected images using open cv but the problem is that it gives me assertation failure in which it fails to capture the frame. The first frame is captured successfully but the subsequent fails.

my code:

```
import cv2
import uuid
import os
import time

imagesPath = "Tensorflow/workspace/images/collectedimages"

if not os.path.exists(imagesPath):
    os.makedirs(imagesPath)
    
labels = ['hello', 'thankyou', 'yes', 'no', 'iloveyou']
numberImages = 20

for label in labels:
    labelPath = os.path.join(imagesPath, label)
    
    if not os.path.exists(labelPath):
        os.makedirs(labelPath)
        
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    print("Collecting images for {}".format(label))
    for num in range(numberImages):
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        print("ret:", ret)
        imageName = os.path.join(imagesPath, label, label + "." + "{}.jpg".format(str(uuid.uuid1())))
        print("imageName:", imageName)
        cv2.imwrite(imageName,frame)
        cv2.imshow('captureImages',frame)
        time.sleep(2)
        
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
        cap.release()
```

Below are the output and error:

```
Collecting images for hello
ret: True
imageName: Tensorflow/workspace/images/collectedimages\hello\hello.701b06f0-24a3-11ee-8d31-0068eb8c6ae0.jpg
ret: False
imageName: Tensorflow/workspace/images/collectedimages\hello\hello.717b980e-24a3-11ee-87ef-0068eb8c6ae0.jpg
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[9], line 14
     12 imageName = os.path.join(imagesPath, label, label + "." + "{}.jpg".format(str(uuid.uuid1())))
     13 print("imageName:", imageName)
---> 14 cv2.imwrite(imageName,frame)
     15 cv2.imshow('captureImages',frame)
     16 time.sleep(2)

error: OpenCV(4.6.0) C:\b\abs_d8ltn27ay8\croot\opencv-suite_1676452046667\work\modules\imgcodecs\src\loadsave.cpp:801: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_img.empty() in function 'cv::imwrite'
```

Answer and find a solution to my problem

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You put `cap.release()` in your for loop, after you read your first image, the cap stream no longer exists. Therefore, when you read it you get a `ret=False` and you can't obtain a frame from it.

Answer (score 0):

From the output you gave, it shows `ret: False`. That clearly indicates that there is no image there.
What you have done is, you have released the object (`cap.release()`) as soon as the first iteration has been completed. And later on, you have not recreated the object again. You need to shift that to the condition check.

```
if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
    cap.release()
    break
```

That way only when you press 'q' the object is disposed. Hope this clears it up.